# unable to play local audio .wav file with wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, html, wavesurfer.js

i unable to play my local audio file in wavesurfer.js. If i pass direct local file path to load method it raises the exception in browser console. Could any one solve me this with snippet will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance
Here is my code

```
       var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
           container: '#player',
           waveColor: 'violet',
           progressColor: 'purple',
           scrollParent: true,
           hideScrollbar: true
       });

       wavesurfer.load("C://user/bla bla...");
```

here it raises error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read directly from the hard drive with Javascript. You need to save the file on the web server, or if you are running the JS file, then locally save the file in the same folder as the js files and change:

```
wavesurfer.load("C://user/bla bla...");
```

to:

```
wavesurfer.load("file_name");
```

Comment: in my scenario the audio file are sitted some other drive of server meaching file system, so i get the files from there with that i am asking